# How to validate phone number(US format) in Java?

Tags: java

I just want to know where am i wrong here:

```
import java.io.*;


    class Tokens{   
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
               //String[] result = "this is a test".split("");

                String[] result = "4543 6546 6556".split("");
                boolean flag= true;         

                String num[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
                String specialChars[] = {"-","@","#","*"," "};


                for (int x=1; x<result.length; x++)
                {   
                    for (int y=0; y<num.length; y++)
                    {
                        if ((result[x].equals(num[y])))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                            continue;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            flag = true;
                        }


                        if (flag == true)
                        break;

                    }   

                if (flag == false)
                break;

                }           

                System.out.println(flag);

            }

    }
```

Comment: *"Use a regexp"* answer in 3..2..1 followed by *"When you have a problem and use a regexp, now you have two problems"* jokes in 3..2..1 ; )

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: you're late, the "use a regexp" answer came *before* your comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asides from the regex suggestion (which is a good one), it would seem to make more sense to deal with arrays of *characters* rather than single-char Strings.

In particular, the `split("")` call (shudder) could/should be replaced by `toCharArray()`.  This lets you iterate over each individual character, which more clearly indicates your intent, is less prone to bugs as you *know* you're treating each character at once, and is more efficient*.  Likewise your valid character sets should also be characters.

Your logic is pretty strangely expressed; you're not even referencing the specialChars set at all, and the looping logic once you've found a match seems odd.  I think this is your bug; the matching seems to be the wrong way round in that if the character matches the *first* valid char, you set flag to `false` and continue round the current loop; so it will definitely not match the next valid char and hence you break out of the loop with a `true` flag.  Always.

I would have thought something like this would be more intuitive:

```
private static final Set<Character> VALID_CHARS = ...;

public boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String number)
{
    for (char c : number,toCharArray())
    {
        if (!VALID_CHARS.contains(c))
        {
           return false;
        }
    }

    // All characters were valid
    return true;
}
```

This doesn't take sequences into account (e.g. the strings "--------**  " and "1" would be valid because all individual characters are valid) but then neither does your original code.  A regex is better because it lets you specify the pattern, I supply the above snippet as an example of a clearer way of iterating through the characters.

*Yes, premature optimization is the root of all evil, but when *better*, *cleaner* code also happens to be faster that's an extra win for free.

Answer (score 3):

If this is not homework, is there a reason you're avoiding regular expressions?

Here are some useful ones: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7

More generally, your code doesn't seem to validate that you have a phone number, it seems to merely validate that your strings consists only of digits. You're also not allowing any special characters right now.

Comment: This is just for the sake of practice. What you suggest what's the best method for validation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is overkill, but with a grammar similar to:

```
<phone_numer> := <area_code><space>*<local_code><space>*<number> |
                 <area_code><space>*"-"<space>*<local_code><space>*"-"<space>*<number>
<area_code>   := <digit><digit><digit> | 
                 "("<digit><digit><digit>")"
<local_code>  := <digit><digit><digit>
<number>      := <digit><digit><digit><digit>
```

you can write a recursive descent parser. See [this page](http://www.faqs.org/docs/javap/c11/s5.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the Pattern class in Java, really easy to work with regular expression using this class:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.